# NDB Python Deleting Entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entity

I have this code, which is suppose to delete **all** entities, but all it's doing is creating an empty entity

```
Class_data = Class_Name.query().fetch()
for classX in Class_data:
    class_json_pre = json.dumps(classX)
    class_json = json.loads(class_json_pre)
    class_delete = Class_Name.get_by_id(class_json.class_name)
    class_delete.delete()
```

A Class_Name is created like this

```
new_class = Class_Name(class_title = new_dictionary,class_name = classname, id = classname)
```

Comment: Possible case conflict: 'Class_data' vs 'class_data'?

Comment: i changed it, but I'm still getting a new empty entity

Comment: How that JSON code is related? Why are you fetching all entities and then trying to get it again by its ID? Why you're not calling delete() method on *key* as it's supposed to be called?

Comment: I ended up making a HTML error so that's why I kept getting new entities. I ended up using the delete() method. Thanks!